# stutter/flicker in 3d transform for firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, transform

I came across [**THIS SITE**](http://blog.qr4.nl/) today and the `3dtransform` of the QR code was unbearable in `FF`.

I viewed the same site in `Chrome` and the animation was much smoother. I wanted to know what was going on so I viewed the source and stripped out the non-pertinent info and created a fiddle:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PLZ2j/)

The core code I pulled from that site is here:

HTML

```
<div class="QRcode3d">
    <img alt="QR Code Cube 1" src="http://blog.qr4.nl/images/QR-Cube-1.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.QRcode3d {
    height: 331px;
    margin: 150px auto;
    position: relative;
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    width: 331px;
    animation: 30s linear 0s normal none infinite spin1;
    display: block;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin1 {
    0% {-webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(450deg) rotateZ(0deg);}
}

@keyframes spin1 {
    0% {transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg);}
    100% {transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(450deg) rotateZ(0deg);}
```

}

The only [**BUG REPORT**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=808155) I've seen on the topic doesn't have much info in the way of 'solving' the issue.. there is even difficulty in reproducing it.

Going to [**CanIUse**](http://caniuse.com/#search=3dtransform) shows that it was available on my version of FF, and even toggling `hardware acceleration` in the `FF` browser didn't really alter the situation.

*Does anyone know the root cause of the 3D Transform issue in FF, and what may be done to remedy the situation?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the perspective out of the animation and put it into the main rule:

```
.QRcode3d {
    height: 331px;
    margin: 150px auto;
    position: relative;
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    width: 331px;
    animation: 30s linear 0s normal none infinite spin1;
    display: block;
    perspective: 600px;
}
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PLZ2j/1/

Updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PLZ2j/2/) (for Chrome)

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I added that fiddle because the one I posted neglected to have the `-webkit-` vendor prefix on the `animation` rule. I updated that, and removed the `perspective` from the animation rule.